# How the returned function is not destroying event listener in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made this custom hook to get window width. It is working but I have a question.
I used `useEffect` to add event listener to `window` at component mount. But then my friend suggested me to use `return` function to remove the event listener.
How this is working? Shouldn't the returned function destroy the event listener and make it not work? Since this is happing one time on component mount ?

```
import React from "react";

const useWindowSize = () => {
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = React.useState({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
  });
  const windowResize = () => {
    setWindowSize({
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
    });
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", windowResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", windowResize);
    };
  }, []);
  return windowSize;
};

export default useWindowSize;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> shouldn't return function destroy event listener and make it not
> work? since this is happing one time on component mount ?

The return function will be executed in your case when the component using the hook *unmounts* (because of empty array as dependencies). So at that time it makes sense to unregister the listener I suppose. More [reading](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

Comment: oh I got it. that means if I use for example router. and move to another component. this return function will be executed. 

Answer (score 2):

The returned function inside the `useEffect` gets executed just before your component gets unmounted. It is not executed on mount.

Without this returned function, every time your component re-renders, if you hadn't that empty array dependency, and when it gets unmounted and mounted, a new `EventListener` is added in memory (which is bad).

Answer (score 1):

This callback in return of `useEffect` is called on `unmount`. Which means that eventListener is removed when your component is no longer rendered, or when its "remounted" (key prop was changed). This is important because without removing event listener, there will be several same eventListeners hooked at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

try code:

```
    const windowResize = useCallback(event => {
        setWindowSize({
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight,
        });
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("keydown", windowResize);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("keydown", windowResize);
        };
    }, [windowResize]);
```